# Are there any differences between "supernatural" and "paranormal"?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, differences, adjectives

Are there any differences between "supernatural" and "paranormal"?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As *super* means *above* and *para* means *beyond*, I would say the differences lie in the parts *natural* and *normal*.

In the mere word sense something *paranormal* is just beyond normal. *Natural* can be interpreted as synonym to *normal* in the sense of *something comes natural* and the like. It can be interpreted as another realm as well, the realm of God as opposed to the realm of man.

As @Aidas would use *paranormal* for the mysterious, one could argue that the realm of God is *paranormal*. But it is very unusual to talk of the realm and the workings of God as *paranormal*, while it is perfectly normal to call effects believed to be caused by UFO's, aliens (from outer space), or ghosts *paranormal*.

In addition it seems more fitting to call effects *paranormal*, while *supernatural* would also be used for beings.

*paranormal* is translated into German as *übersinnlich*, above the sense realm, while *supernatural* is translated *überirdisch, übermenschlich, übernatürlich*: above earthly, above humane, supernatural.

Comment: I would say Supernatural is something that's still in the realm of natural perception, even when is above normal. Ex. "Supernatural strength, supernatural intelligence". 

In the other hand, Paranormal breaks the normality cause the origin is out of normal, natural. Ex. "Sounds were paranormal, the light was paranormal".

In the case of the light, the supernatural light could still be light, in the paranormal light could be a light that doesn't behaves as light, as a wave (well that's natural but would be so weird that surely fall into paranormal).

Answer (score 0):

Being not a native English speaker, I would use "paranormal" for mysterious and unexplainable, whereas I would use "supernatural" for fictional and superior than normal.